# PowerShell - can´t find long path but file exists

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I have an issue while trying to run a PowerShell script.
When i try to obtain a file content (ex. `Get-Content ".\d\e\file.xml"`) using a script a few directories bellow this .xml it works.
But, if i run this script from a different directory to get the file content (ex. `c:\users\x\desktop`), it will not be able to read it. I have tried `Set-Location -Path "C:\a\b\c\` so it can get by relative path.

This is the error that I´m having:

Cannot find path 'C:\a\b\c\d\e\file.xml' because it does not exist.  (path has 263 characters, too long)

Powershell Version : 5.1.18362.628

Comment: You could possibly use the long path name --> `Get-Content '\\?\c:\a\b\c\d\e\file.xml'`. This just means prefixing the full path with ```\\?\```.

Comment: i tried it already, this leads to another error: "An object at the specified path \\?\C:\.....file.xml does not exist, or has been filtered by the -Include or -Exclude parameter." Might need to add "-LiteralPath"

Comment: Please post the code that produces your errors and what you have tried.

Comment: LongPathsEnabled : 1

Comment: @AdminOfThings , sorry, i will try to give as much context as i can. I´m using chocolatey to install a .numpkg, on the chocoinstall script i use `& "$ScriptRoot\FileReaderScript.ps1"` so it runs my script. on "FileReaderScript" i run `[xml]$xmlDoc = (Get-Content "c:\a\b\c\d\e....file.xml)` , but if i run the "fileReaderScript on ""c:\a\b\c" it will work with this line of code.

Comment: One more thing: if i try to edit the file name i cannot as path is too long, but still, i can read/write it when the script it´s few folders behind .xml file

Comment: Push-Location and Pop-Location might be of use? The length of a path in Windows is limited to 260 chars.